# Cast SQL Server column from real to float without introducing small errors

Tags: sql-server, casting, floating-point, precision

I am working with a SQL Server database where I need to get data from a column with the type `real` into another column in another table with the type `float`. From my understanding, `real` is essentially just float with less precision (24) compared to `float` which by default has a precision of 53. Therefore, when casting from real to float I would expect to actually get more precision or at least not lose the precision of the source value. However, some precision actually seems to be lost when doing this:

[image: Conversion real to float]

Why does this happen and is there a way to at least keep the precision of the source values when doing this?

Comment: The *real* question is why are you using `float` and `real` if you want precise values.

Comment: @Larnu I don't know. I have not developed this database and from my knowledge it is quite a few years old. There is already 100GB+ of data in this database and there is new data written to it every few minutes so I don't know if there is an easy way to change the data types of the columns at this point. Is that possible?

Comment: You can easily change the data type of a column using `ALTER`; though if there are `CONSTRAINTS` and `INDEX`es on the columns, you'll need to `DROP` them first and recreate them afterwards. Also if there are any schemabound objects referencing them, those will need to be dropped and recreated too.

Comment: @Larnu Can these changes be done quickly though or would it take longer the more data is already in the database? What would happen when new data is written to the database while it is still in the process of altering the tables?

Comment: Your source values are not precise - SSMS just displays them this way.

Comment: @Arvo Oh, okay. And this happens only with real and not with float values?

Comment: *"Can these changes be done quickly though"* technically you could use a dynamic statement to `ALTER` them all, but it would certainly not take into consideration any other objects that would block the operation. What you would really want to do is make the migration script in your development environment, so that you have a large batch that performs all the changes; and as it's dev it doesn't matter what you break. As for what would happen while you `ALTER` the table, the queries would  likely be blocked until the DDL statement completes.

Comment: `float` is still an imprecise data type. Both `real` and `float` are.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! And yeah, I know that both `real` and `float` are imprecise but I am confused why SSMS rounds `real` values when displaying them but does not do the same for `float` values

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused why SSMS rounds real values when displaying them but does not do the same for float values

The nearest single-precision floating point number (`real`) to 2.1 is something like 2.0999999.  So it makes sense to display it as 2.1.

The nearest double-precision floating point number (`float`) to 2.1 is quite a long way from
2.09999990000000, which is approximately what you get when you convert 2.0999999 from `real` to `float`.

SSMS will display a floats closer to 2.1 as 2.1, eg

```
select cast(2.1 as float), cast(2.1 as float) - 0.000000000000001
```

is displayed as

```
---------------------- ----------------------
2.1                    2.1
```

Here's a paper that reviews algorithms for this conversion and presents a new one: [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately with
Integers](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Just as addition to David Browne answer:

Looks like direct casting doesn't help you. You can get 'correct' (better) results, casting through the character type, like next:

```
select cast(cast(Valuef as nvarchar(20)) as float)
```

As an example, `select cast(cast(cast(2.1 as real) as nvarchar(20)) as float)` displays just `2.1`.